# Is there a version of the Stack Overflow app for the iOS simulator?

Tags: discussion, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

I am writing a test framework which targets Web, Android and iOS testing. I would love to use Stack Overflow as a quick proof of concept demo for it, i.e. showcase that I can run the same (read-only) testcase against all three platforms. [Web](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow) are straightforward, but there's no simple way to automate testing the [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808).

I understand that the code is closed source, but would it be possible to provide a version for the iOS simulator?